# Как на Golang передать значения другой программе?

Tags: golang

Есть запущенный exe файл на golang на удалённом компьютере.
В момент обновления мне нужно с другой программы(на том же компьютере) подать команду этому процессу- "закройся", после чего он закрывается и копируется новый exe и потом он запускается. Как мне передать значение программе и потом открыть файл?

Comment: Весьма сумбурно. IPC в Go реализуется через сеть: [net/rpc](http://godoc.org/net/rpc) или [net/rpc/jsonrpc](http://godoc.org/net/rpc/jsonrpc). Остальные способы зависят от платформы и скорее всего о них лучше узнать у программистов C.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант через [сигналы](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/).

Заставляешь свою программу при старте создавать .pid файл, куда записывать PID ее процесса. Подписываешь ее на сигналы (можно фильтровать 2ым параметром к Notify) и аккуратно завершаешь прогу при получении сигнала, удаляя .pid файл.

```
ch := make(chan<- os.Signal)
signal.Notify(ch)

go func(){
    <- ch
    // вставь свой механизм завершения
    // например
    server.stop()
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Из "другой" программы (назовем апдейтер), читаешь PID из файла, находишь процесс по PID os.FindProcess, посылаешь сигнал твоей программе os.Process.Signal, дожидаешься завершения os.Process.Wait, копируешь новый файл, запускаешь.
Смотри в сторону os и signal, но "Signal sends a signal to the Process. Sending Interrupt on Windows is not implemented.", поэтому настраивайся на какой нить SIGUSR2.

Вариант 2: "сервер".
"Cервер" программа запускается, порождает потомка Worker через [syscall.ForkExec](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#ForkExec) (отдельный exe'шник) и "засыпает" в ожидании оповещений через тот же signal от апдейтера (апдейтер в этот момент перезаписывает exe'шник Workera.
Когда сигнал приходит, например SIGUSR2, она посылает сигнал этому потомку, он удачно завершается, после чего вызывается новый syscall.ForkExec уже для нового бинарника, засыпаем и так по кругу.
Завершение такого сервера можно настроить по другому сигналу, например SIGUSR1.

Разница между подходами в том, что во втором случае ты можешь вынести всю логику по скачиванию, перезапуску и даже версионированию в сам "сервер", а от третьей стороны потребуется только посылать сигнал.

Ты же не уточнял что такое "другая" программа на том же компе, твоя ли она, или это действительно какая нить 1C со своими ограничениями. А так ты можешь даже написать 3ю прогу на golang, которая только и будет что тыкать в "сервер" по инфе из pid файла "сервера" и завершаться.